# Document format: Two columns first page, one column second

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying (and failing) to create a Microsoft Word document that has two columns on the first page, and one column on every succeeding page.

The idea is that the first page has a list of people in the organization down the left-hand edge of the page in a narrow column, and the wider right-hand column has the text (letter or report text).

I can sort-of make this work if I insert a section break at the page break, but the section break keeps moving down the document, and I want to explicitly change sections at the second page (so that each succeeding page is just normal text in one column).

I thought I could put a section break at the end of the page, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Failing that, if someone has any other suggestions as to how to achieve what I need, that'd be great!

If it makes a difference, I'm using MS Word for Mac 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve it with column settings, instead:

To make the first column in the first page just insert a table of one cell (or a text box, that will do the same)

- set its height to be the same as the page's height
- set with to the desired value
- set text to be wrapped around it
- remove borders to make your first column look like the normal text.

Comment: Thank-you! That did it for me!  I should have thought of that first, but I inherited the document and was trying to make it work the way the original author was doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this can, in fact, be done. If you go to Layout > Breaks > Section Breaks > Next Page, it will allow you to format one section with a certain number of columns and the other section with a different number of columns.

Hope that helps someone else down the road!

Comment: I don't think this works to solve the OP's problem. This automatically forces the new section to start on a new page, but still requires that you place a section break after the text that fills the first page. That location will likely change from one document to another. The OP (I think) was trying to get the text that flowed automatically to the second page to be formatted in one column, and have that formatting remain even if additional text is added to the first page.