# add single column pages after multi column word template

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have used a word resume template that has multiple columns, and it turned out well.

I would like to add some additional pages to the document (certificates, letters of reference, etc) but in single column format.  However, when I do a page break and go to single column, the formatting of the resume template changes, breaking up the first page template formatting.

This previous post;
[Document format: Two columns first page, one column second](https://superuser.com/questions/1031826/document-format-two-columns-first-page-one-column-second)
described a similar problem and they suggested using tables instead of columns on the first page, but I have no idea how to convert a word resume template into tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A table is rarely if ever necessary for layout purposes in Word. Just insert a Next Page section break, instead of a page break, where you want the new page to start; then format the new page (that is, the new section) so that it has just 1 column. Different sections can have a different number of columns, different page orientations,  and different page sizes, etc.